# Try to Scrape Instacart: Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am having trouble trying to webscrape instacart using the requests library in python. I want to get past the first initial page that asks for the zip code and move onto the email page. Here is my code:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
data = {"address_line_1":"MYZIPCODE"}
header = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3"}
response = requests.post('https://www.instacart.com/', headers=header, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

I was wondering if you guys could help.

BTW: I am using `address_line_1` because that is the name of the input.
Thanks

Comment: Seems like the website is rendered using JavaScript, but the requests library works only with static code. Try to open the website in your browser while JavaScript is disabled. In that case, the form isn't rendered.
You can use something like headless Chrome and [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev) for rendering JS.

Comment: ^ Agreed. However, it depends on the type of data you want to extract. Looks like you could use `https://www.instacart.com/v3/dynamic_data/authenticate/postal_code_check?source=web&cache_key=undefined&signup_location_type=address_and_zip&postal_code=00000`, where 00000 is your zip code, to get certain data.

Comment: Thanks you guys so much. Will do.

Comment: I had one more question: if I wanted to get delivery times, what are my options to do so?

Comment: I updated my answer below with delivery time info. In short, you could either scrape the customer-facing webpage (listed below) or use the JSON interface that is called by that  webpage to get the information in the first place.

Comment: I've noticed a recent change in the Instacart website whereby the prices render after the rest of the page. I also noticed that they changed some of the class names to more abstract ones, for example, `.full-item-name` to `.css-15uwigl`, `.item-size` to `.css-1kh7mkb`, and `.item-price` to `.css-coqxwd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No guarantees, as this answer is the result of some brief experimentation, but I might have found a solution.

I poked around on the website, and discovered that when I reloaded the page, the initial screen asking for your zip code/email was skipped. I then deleted the session cookie, `_instacart_session`, but left all other cookies intact, and was asked to sign in again.

This suggests that if you sign in manually using your browser, and then save the `_instacart_session` cookie that is generated, you could bypass the sign-in process. Send the cookie along with the requests you make in your program, and you might be able to skip directly to `http://instacart.com/store/NAME_OF_STORE/storefront`.

There might even be another cookie that remembers your desired location, thus bypassing that selection screen as well (but I am not sure of this).

---

Edit: I see **delivery times** listed in the JSON info for each store, with URLs like `https://www.instacart.com/v3/containers/NAME_OF_STORE/next_gen/retailer_information/content/delivery?source=web`. You need to navigate to `https://www.instacart.com/store/NAME_OF_STORE/info?tab=delivery` first to set your cookies, else I get an `Unauthorized` error message.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, also use `_instacart_logged_in` = `1`.

Comment: Also, where did you get the links from?

Comment: I used the network tab of my browser's developer tools to capture the JSON requests, then looked at the headers of each to find the request URL. If you navigate the site normally with the network tab open and 'persist logs' on, you might find some different interfaces that work too.

Comment: Perfect Thanks. I also just looked up https://www.instacart.com/v3/ and got all the links I needed. Thanks so much.